# How to divide multiple dataframes to multiple new dataframes via formula?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have M1 to M370 dataframes and i need to split each dataframe in six new dataframes based on median of variable A the  dataframe has and then these new dataframes by quantiles of variable B. So in total 6 dataframes are created from each M1 to M370. While i can do these new dataframes individually i cant create a loop function that does it automatically for every single dataframe. My manual formula for dataframe M1 is following:

```
M1highA <- M1[M1$X > median(M1$A),]
M1highA_highB <- M1highA[M1highX$B > quantile(M1highA$B, probs =0.7),]
M1highA_mediumB <-M1highA[M1highA$B < quantile(M1highA$B, probs = 0.7) & 
                          M1highA$B > quantile(M1highA$B, probs = 0.3) ,]
M1highA_lowB<- M1highA[M1highA$B < quantile(M1highA$B, probs =0.3),]
```

and same for the low A.

My basic knowledge of loop function runs out when trying this.

Comment: I would think about whether creating 6 x 370 is the best solution for whatever you are trying to achieve. It's very likely that **filtering** the existing data frames is a more efficient and practical approach.

Comment: Is there any guide for creating such data portfolio? It seems the loop function would be so fast because if the data set needs changing it can run it fast

Comment: I was able to turn it in to a formula that has only M1 dataframe, so for example there are no M1highA , but still looping it is something i can not do